# Can there be another "Terminator" sequel?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

Assuming the Genisys time line is only one. How can another Terminator movie be done without being stupid or a re-boot?

Comment: There is no way that they can make another sequel without it being stupid.

Comment: @Richard Why change course now?

Comment: Why assume the Genisys timeline is the only one? The writers of Genisys didn't, they said in interviews they imagined a multiverse model (see their answer to "Where does the Matt Smith Skynet come from at the beginning of the movie" [here](http://io9.gizmodo.com/your-burning-questions-about-the-plot-of-terminator-gen-1715234003)).

Comment: Ian Malcom has your answer: "You were so busy with whether or not you could you didn't stop to think if you should" ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Uncertain.  The Terminator franchise is on hold.

Given the mixed reception and underwhelming box office performance of *Terminator: Genisys*, it was announced by producer David Ellison that there are no longer are any plans to produce a sequel that ties up the loose ends in *Genisys*, and the Terminator franchise as a whole is now on hold.

Read these for instance:

- **[Terminator sequels on hold indefinitely; Oct 1, 2015](http://screenrant.com/terminator-genisys-sequels-indefinite-hold/)**
- **[Terminator franchise put on "indefinite hold" because of domestic box office performance; Oct 4, 2015](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/terminator-genisys-sequels-put-on-indefinite-hold-because-film-performed-poorly-at-domestic-box-a6678871.html)**

Given the negative reaction, it seems that the Genisys timeline has been abandoned, in contrast to your assumption.  If the Terminator franchise is resurrected, it is very unlikely to pick up from where Genisys leaves off.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

At the end of Genisys, we see that

> John Connor survived.

He will inevitably attempt to rebuild Skynet. Judgment Day has once again only been delayed.

Edit: I may be wrong about exactly *what* survived, but something did. See [this article](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Terminator-Genisys-Post-Credits-Scene-What-Happens-What-It-Means-72377.html).

Comment: Please explain how John Connor survives. Am I missing some post credits info?

Comment: @chanjoobrown, yes it was post credits.

Comment: I think the "infant" Skynet of that timeline survived, not John Connor.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, (Matt Smith) survived.